# Caminho imagem Console Application VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Ola gostaria de uma ajuda por favor com relação a um problema que estou tendo para inserir uma imagem no meu projeto console application.
Só consigo usar o caminho absoluto quando mandar o projeto o cliente vai ter que mudar como faço para isso não precisar acontecer?

```
Private Function cabecalhoPolicardPDF() As PdfPTable
    Try
        Dim img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("G:\projetolimpo\up_sgp-master\RotinaRelacaoLimiteComplementar\img\logo-sombra.jpg")
    Dim table = New PdfPTable(2)
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        table.TotalWidth = 500
        Dim widths() As Integer = {190, 310}
        table.SetWidths(widths)

        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(img)
        cell.Border = 0
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
        cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE


        Dim cell2 As New PdfPCell()

        Dim VerdanaCab As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 13, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)
        VerdanaCab.SetColor(245, 145, 0)
        Dim Verdana As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)
        Dim VerdanaN As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)

        Dim p0 As New Phrase()
        Dim c1 As New Chunk("SISTEMA UP BRASIL" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine, VerdanaCab)
        p0.Add(c1)
        p0.Leading = 50

        cell2.AddElement(p0)
        cell2.SetLeading(0.0F, 0.0F)


        c1 = New Chunk("Razão Social: ", Verdana)
        Dim c2 As New Chunk("Policard Systems e Serviços S/A" & Environment.NewLine, VerdanaN)
        Dim p1 As New Phrase()

        p1.Leading = 10
        p1.Add(c1)
        p1.Add(c2)


        cell2.AddElement(p1)

        cell2.Border = 0
        cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        table.AddCell(cell2)
        table.AddCell(cell)
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT

        Return table
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Inclua o seu código de fato e não um print da tela... O arquivo vai estar na mesma estrutura do executável? vai usar alguma variável de ambiente? salvar no app.settings ou em algum arquivo de config?

Comment: Olá Leandro, certo vou colocar o código, bom sim estará na mesma estrutura, funcionará assim terei uma console application que utilizara esses metodos para criar um PDF e preciso que no pdf tenha esse logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que a raiz do seu executável esteja em 
`G:\projetolimpo\up_sgp-master\` você pode utilizar o método `GetCurrentDirectory()` e complementar com restante do caminho.

```
Dim path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\RotinaRelecaoLimiteComplementar\\img\\logo-sombra.jpg"

Dim img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar uma forma para que seu cliente possa editar esse valor por meio da sua aplicação que deverá armazenar essa informação  de forma persistente em um arquivo de texto ou banco, ou você pode ter uma variável global que receba esse valor, (nessa segunda opção o valor será armazenado na memória temporária RAM)

Ficaria mais ou menos assim.

```
Dim pathImage string

Dim img=iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(pathImage)
```

Comment: Olá Rodolfo obrigado pela atenção, cara então não tem como eu fazer igual asp net pegar só o caminho da pasta?

Comment: Opa você pode usar o FileDialog para abrir aquela janela de interação para o cliente buscar a imagem em uma pasta em sue computador, ai você armazena o caminho retornado pelo FileDialog, para que na próxima vez ele use esse caminho na exibição de sua imagem, não sei se ficou claro para você essa resposta.

Comment: Olá Rodolfo, mais uma vez obrigado pela atenção bom e que assim essa aplicação e uma rotina que executa de madrugada e monta um PDF eu nunca desenvolvi console aplication então por isso o estranhamento, assim essa opção acho que não funcionaria acho que vou optar por utilizar uma constante mesmo muito obrigado.

Comment: Olá Rodrigo, sendo uma uma aplicação console realmente essa opção não vai funcionar, o ideal é armazenar em uma variável mesmo, mas cria um método, para que você ou seu cliente possa alterar posteriormente.